# Transforming an expression template tree

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, expression-templates

Given an expression template tree, I want to create a new optimized tree before processing it. Consider the following example of a multiplication operation:

```
a * b * c * d,
```

which produces, due to the left-to-right associativity of `operator*`, the expression tree:

```
(((a * b) * c) * d).
```

I would like to produce a transformed expression tree where multiplication occurs from right-to-left:

```
(a * (b * (c * d))).
```

Consider the binary expression type:

```
template<typename Left, typename Right>
struct BinaryTimesExpr
{
    BinaryTimesExpr() = default;
    BinaryTimesExpr(const BinaryTimesExpr&) = default;
    BinaryTimesExpr(BinaryTimesExpr&&) = default;
    BinaryTimesExpr(Left&& l, Right&& r) : left(forward<Left>(l)), right(forward<Right>(r)) {}

    BinaryTimesExpr& operator=(const BinaryTimesExpr&) = default;
    BinaryTimesExpr& operator=(BinaryTimesExpr&&) = default;

    Left left;
    Right right;
};
```

Define the multiplication operator `operator*`:

```
template<typename Left, typename Right>
BinaryTimesExpr<Constify<Left>, Constify<Right>> operator*(Left&& l, Right&& r)
{
    return {forward<Left>(l), forward<Right>(r)};
}
```

where `Constify` is defined by:

```
template<typename T> struct HelperConstifyRef     { using type = T;  };
template<typename T> struct HelperConstifyRef<T&> { using type = const T&; };
template<typename T>
using ConstifyRef = typename HelperConstifyRef<T>::type;
```

and used to ensure sub-expressions with const lvalue-references when constructed from lvalues, and copies (by copy/move) of rvalues when constructed from rvalues.

Define the transformation function that creates a new expression template tree with the previous conditions:

```
template<typename Expr>
auto Transform(const Expr& expr) -> Expr
{
    return expr;
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
auto Transform(const BinaryTimesExpr<Left, Right>& expr) -> type(???)
{
    return {(Transform(expr.left), Transform(expr.right))};
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
auto Transform(const BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<LeftLeft, LeftRight>, Right>& expr) -> type(???)
{
    return Transform({Transform(expr.left.left), {Transform(expr.left.right), Transform(expr.right)}}); // this sintax is invalid...how can I write this?
}
```

My questions are:

1) How do I determine the return types of the `Transform` functions? I've tried using type traits like:

```
template<typename Expr>
struct HelperTransformedExpr
{
    using type = Expr;
};

template<typename Left, typename Right>
struct HelperTransformedExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<Left, Right>>
{
    using type = BinaryTimesExpr<typename HelperTransformedExpr<Left>::type, typename HelperTransformedExpr<Right>::type>;
};

template<typename LeftLeft, typename LeftRight, typename Right>
struct HelperTransformedExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<LeftLeft, LeftRight>, Right>>
{
    using type = BinaryTimesExpr<typename HelperTransformedExpr<LeftLeft>::type,
        BinaryTimesExpr<typename HelperTransformedExpr<LeftRight>::type, typename HelperTransformedExpr<Right>::type>>;
};

template<typename Expr>
using TransformedExpr = typename HelperTransformedExpr<Expr>::type;
```

but don't know how to apply this to solve my question (2) below.

2) How do I write the recursion line:

```
return Transform({Transform(expr.left.left), {Transform(expr.left.right), Transform(expr.right)}});
```

3) Is there a *cleaner* solution for this problem?

---

**Edit:** DyP presents a partial solution to the above problem. Below is my full solution based on his answer:

```
template<typename Expr>
auto Transform(const Expr& expr) -> Expr
{
    return expr;
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
auto Transform(BinaryTimesExpr<Left, Right> const& expr)
-> decltype(BinaryTimesExpr<decltype(Transform(expr.left)), decltype(Transform(expr.right))>{Transform(expr.left), Transform(expr.right)})
{
    return BinaryTimesExpr<decltype(Transform(expr.left)), decltype(Transform(expr.right))>{Transform(expr.left), Transform(expr.right)};
}

template<typename LeftLeft, typename LeftRight, typename Right>
auto Transform(BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<LeftLeft, LeftRight>, Right> const& expr)
-> decltype(Transform(BinaryTimesExpr<decltype(Transform(expr.left.left)), BinaryTimesExpr<decltype(Transform(expr.left.right)), decltype(Transform(expr.right))>>{Transform(expr.left.left), {Transform(expr.left.right), Transform(expr.right)}}))
{
    return Transform(BinaryTimesExpr<decltype(Transform(expr.left.left)), BinaryTimesExpr<decltype(Transform(expr.left.right)), decltype(Transform(expr.right))>>{Transform(expr.left.left), {Transform(expr.left.right), Transform(expr.right)}});
}

int main()
{
    BinaryTimesExpr<int, int> beg{1,2};
    auto res = beg*3*4*5*beg;
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    std::cout << Transform(res) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
(((((1*2)*3)*4)*5)*(1*2))
(1*(2*(3*(4*(5*(1*2))))))
```

Note that it was necessary to apply the `Transform` function on every sub-expression besides the most external `Transform` call (see the last `Transform` overload).

The full source code can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4e484c38472ed19ed9c42fcc8e30a617-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852).

Comment: Have you considered using Boost.Proto to help out with this? Cpp Next seems to be down at the moment, but he did an article about using Proto to re-order math expressions. His example was (A+B)[2] into A[2]+B[2], but since they're all just operators, it ought to apply.

Comment: This is going to be integrated in a library that should not require  third-party dependencies.

Comment: 1) Boost.Proto is header-only. 2) Do you want to have metaprogramming transformer that transforms `(((a * b) * c) * d)` into `(a * (b * (c * d)))` or would it be sufficient to build the expression tree directly as `(a * (b * (c * d)))`?

Comment: You want an expression like `((((a * b) * c) * d) * e)` wich evaluates to `binary_exp<binary_exp<binary_exp<binary_exp<decltype(a),decltype(b)>,decltype(c)>,decltype(d)>,decltype(e)>` , have to be evaluated as `binary_exp<decltype(a),binary_exp<decltype(b),binary_exp<decltype(c),binary_exp<decltype(d),decltype(e)>>>>` right? Why you don't simply returns the expression in reverse order, in the operators overloads?

Comment: that is: `template<typename Left ,typename Right> binary_exp<Right,Left> operator*(const Left& lhs , const Right& rhs) { return { std::forward<Right>( rhs ) , std::forward<Left>( lhs ) }; }`

Comment: @Manu343726 First iteration: `a*b` -> `exp<B,A>`. Second iteration: `exp<B,A>*c` -> `exp<C,exp<B,A>>`. This doesn't help if each `exp` shall perform one multiplication.

Comment: @Manu343726 Yes, this solves the problem, but as an exercise, I was wondering how those transformations could be applied to the expression tree (resulting in a new tree).

Comment: @DyP I'm seeing that just now... sorry

Comment: @Manu343726 I believe DyP is right. I need recursion to completely solve the problem. Moreover, the order matters when we have matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Allan Order matters with floating point types as well.

Comment: The problem with perfect forwarding I tried to solve is: When `operator *` is allowed to use perfect forwarding, it'll create types like `BinaryTimesExpr<int&, int&>`, and, consequently, also `BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<int,int>&, int>`. This breaks the partial specialization used; maybe it could be fixed using a more generic approach restricted by SFINAE. N.B. rvalues don't profit from (perfect) forwarding here due to lifetime issues.

Comment: @DyP This `BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<Left,Right>&, RightRight>` will not happen if `BinaryTimesExpr<Left, Right>` is a rvalue. See my new edit with the `Constify` type trait. With this, the expression `a * b * C()` becomes `BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<const A&, const B&>, C>`, where the first two terms are lvalues and the third is a rvalue. In my application, the expression nodes should not be instantiated at runtime (they should exist only at compile time).

Comment: The issue I've seen was not non-const refs on the underlying arithmetic types, but on the expression type itself: `BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<int,int>&, int>`, or with your `Constify`, `BinaryTimesExpr<BinaryTimesExpr<int,int> const&, int>`. The problem would be that this doesn't match the third overload of `Transform` (which expects a `BTE<BTE [non-ref], T>`). However, this is solved by your second overload (in a way that a don't understand yet ;).

Answer (score 3):

Although the OP wanted a solution that didn't use Boost.Proto, others might be interested to see how this could be (pretty easily) done using it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>

namespace proto = boost::proto;
using proto::_;

struct empty {};

struct transform
  : proto::reverse_fold_tree<
        _
      , empty()
      , proto::if_<
            boost::is_same<proto::_state, empty>()
          , _
          , proto::_make_multiplies(_, proto::_state)
        >
    >
{};

int main()
{
    proto::literal<int> a(1), b(2), c(3), d(4);
    proto::display_expr( a * b * c * d );
    proto::display_expr( transform()(a * b * c * d) );
}
```

The above code displays:

```
multiplies(
    multiplies(
        multiplies(
            terminal(1)
          , terminal(2)
        )
      , terminal(3)
    )
  , terminal(4)
)
multiplies(
    terminal(1)
  , multiplies(
        terminal(2)
      , multiplies(
            terminal(3)
          , terminal(4)
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without incorporating perfect forwarding:

```
#include <iostream>

// simplified by making it an aggregate
template<typename Left, typename Right>
struct BinaryTimesExpr
{
    Left left;
    Right right;
};

// "debug" / demo output
template<typename Left, typename Right>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, BinaryTimesExpr<Left, Right> const& p)
{
    o << "(" << p.left << "*" << p.right << ")";
    return o;
}

// NOTE: removed reference as universal-ref yields a reference type for lvalues!
template<typename Left, typename Right>
BinaryTimesExpr < typename std::remove_reference<Left>::type,
                  typename std::remove_reference<Right>::type >
operator*(Left&& l, Right&& r)
{
    return {std::forward<Left>(l), std::forward<Right>(r)};
}


// overload to end recursion (no-op)
template<typename Expr>
auto Transform(const Expr& expr) -> Expr
{
    return expr;
}

template<typename LeftLeft, typename LeftRight, typename Right>
auto Transform(BinaryTimesExpr < BinaryTimesExpr<LeftLeft, LeftRight>,
                                 Right > const& expr)
-> decltype(Transform(
     BinaryTimesExpr < LeftLeft,
                       BinaryTimesExpr<LeftRight, Right>
                     > {expr.left.left, {expr.left.right, expr.right}}
   ))
{
    return Transform(
        BinaryTimesExpr < LeftLeft,
                          BinaryTimesExpr<LeftRight, Right>
                        > {expr.left.left, {expr.left.right, expr.right}}
    );
}


int main()
{
    BinaryTimesExpr<int, int> beg{1,2};
    auto res = beg*3*4*5*6;
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    std::cout << Transform(res) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> (((((1*2)*3)*4)*5)*6)
>
> (1*(2*(3*(4*(5*6)))))

Comment: I am getting a strange compilation error when compiling this code: Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered. Anyway, I believe an extra call to `Transform` is necessary in your second overload. Try printing (2*3)*(4*5) to see if (2*(3*(4*5))) is produced.

Comment: @Allan o.O I'm using clang++3.4 [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=678c93dbde7aa7b203ed0cc1ac0ab533-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852)

Comment: @Allan Yes this example doesn't fold, it just "reverses" the tree.

Comment: The `Transform` call needs to be performed on `expr.left.left`, `expr.left.right` and `expr.right`.

Comment: @Allan I'll try to figure out first how to incorporate perfect forwarding. Adding the `Transform` calls to the other two parts is simple AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is really a binary tree. For example, the expression `a * b * c * d * e` is evaluated as `((((a * b) * c) * d) * e)` so what you have is the folowwing tree (Sorry about the three-years-old-child-like drawing, ipad without stylus...):

[image]

As you can see, the default evaluated expression is generated trasversing the tree with **left-side-first inorder**.

On the other hand, the reverse-evaluated expression (What OP wants) is generated trasversing the tree with **right-side-first-inorder**:

[image]

So one solution is to trasverse the generated expression tree in *right-side-first-inorder*, and create a new tree in the process.

Comment: What is the tree is more complex (involving more branches): (2*3)*(4*(5*6))?

Comment: @Allan First note that what I mean with ((a*b)*c) is the form of the expression (How is evaluated) `a * b * c`, that is how the compiler evaluates the expression acording to operators precedence rules. Not what is the tree generated given a expression such as `((a*b)*c)`.